# Incorrect syntax of Chisel

Tags: chisel

I am learning chisel3.

I want to run the code in order to see the result.

Here is my code.[image]

I command "sbt run" and show these errors.
[image]

It seems that I use ".W" to define width is illegal in Chisel,but the user guide obviously tells me that it's correct.

My build.sbt is created like this.

> scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
>
> resolvers ++= Seq(   Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
>   Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases") )
>
> libraryDependencies += "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel3" % "3.0-SNAPSHOT"

What is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the current SNAPSHOT does not include the most up-to-date version of Chisel. I apologize for the published snapshot being behind the documentation. We are working on getting an updated snapshot out now.

EDIT: I believe the published version is now up to date, try `sbt clean` (to remove the old snapshot) and then `sbt run`.